# greenplum gpload : configuration YML file error

Tags: linux, greenplum, hawq

When I try to execute gpload in greenplum, it gives met an error.

**Input command :**

```
[gpadmin@mdw ~]$ gpload -f test.yml
```

**Error that I get**

```
2017-02-25 11:19:13|ERROR|configuration file error: expected <block end>, but found '?', line 9
```

Config YAML file content:

```
VERSION: 1.0.0.1 
DATABASE: gpadmin
USER: gpadmin
HOST: gpdbsne
PORT: 5432
GPLOAD:
   INPUT:
    - SOURCE:
    LOCAL_HOSTNAME:
      - gpdbsne
    PORT: 8999
    FILE:
      - /home/gpadmin/testfile.txt
    - FORMAT: text 
    - DELIMITER: '|'
    - QUOTE: '"'
    - COLUMNS:
       - col1: text
       - col2: text
       - col3: text
       - col4: text
       - col5: text
   OUTPUT:
     - TABLE: public.test
     - MODE: insert 
     - MAPPING:
           col1: col1
           col2: col2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did I understand correctly that data structure is: INPUT - SOURCE  - LOCAL_HOSTNAME ?
If so, add two spaces after SOURCE: Item.
-- Edited according to the comment.
yml config in presented format is highly dependant on tabulations.
So, working config might look as follows:

```
VERSION: 1.0.0.1 
DATABASE: gpadmin
USER: gpadmin
HOST: gpdbsne
PORT: 5432
GPLOAD:
  - INPUT:
    - SOURCE:
      LOCAL_HOSTNAME: gpdbsne
      PORT: 8999
      FILE: /home/gpadmin/testfile.txt
    - FORMAT: text 
    - DELIMITER: '|'
    - QUOTE: '"'
    - COLUMNS:
      - col1: text
      - col2: text
      - col3: text
      - col4: text
      - col5: text
  - OUTPUT:
    - TABLE: public.test
    - MODE: insert 
    - MAPPING:
      - col1: col1
      - col2: col2
```

Comment: Could you please provide json or any other data model representation? I shall form it for you in yml config.

Comment: Thanks i just rechecked . it is working . currently, getting this 
2017-02-25 18:34:24|ERROR|unexpected key: "local_hostname"

Comment: yml config style always bores. It is really important to have data model first and understand that there are 3 types of values: single, key-value and list. All of them can be mixed by tabulation.

Comment: Thank you i applied and process started only i am facing this https://paste.ofcode.org/F3qq57WrFjbUAe2nNLgcKN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136639/discussion-between-sylphes-and-etech).

Comment: Sorry, no. I am not in gpload. Just spent plenty of time with yml configs.